# How to send data over HTTP from server to BlackBerry client?

Tags: jsp, blackberry

I am using JSP for server side programming and client is a BlackBerry 8520. How can I send some data from server to the client? This mobile does not have the GPS feature.

Comment: use Http protocle.I think you request a http url(your server url) from your phone and process the response from the server in your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send some data as HTTP response from server to client on demand. If it were possible, the world wide web would have looked very different. The client has first to explicitly send a HTTP request for it, so that the server can send the data back as HTTP response.

In the BlackBerry's Java ME API, you can use [the `HttpConnection` API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) to create a HTTP request and retrieve the HTTP response programmatically.

#### See also:

- [BlackBerry How To - Establish a HTTP connection](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800429/How_To_-_Establish_an_HTTP_connection.html?nodeid=800632&vernum=0)
- [BlackBerry Forums - Connecting your BlackBerry - http and socket connections to the world](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206242)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if the HTTP response is not a HTML page, then you're supposed to use a servlet class for this instead of a JSP file or, better, a JAX-RS/WS webservice. Remember: once you start writing Java code in JSPs by `<% %>`, then you're already approaching things wrong.